# filter for and delete rows in excel using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am still very new to powershell and feel like this might be a simple question, but I am stuck on my program trying to filter my excel spreadsheet, and then delete the filtered rows.

ideally I would like to filter for all the rows that do NOT say "NO DATA" in column A starting at Row 3. 
once I have all of those rows I would like to delete them all. 
Then bring back all the rows that have "NO DATA"

what I cant figure out is how to write the script so that the filter starts at row 2, and how to filter for all the rows that do NOT say "NO DATA"

```
$worksheet.usedrange.autofilter(1, -ne "NO DATA", 3)
$worksheet.usedrange.offset(1,0).specialcells(12).Entirerow.Delete() 
$worksheet.ShowAllData()
```

when I try what seems logical to me I get 2 errors, one is "missing expression" after the',' before -ne, and the other is "unable to get the Auto filter property of the range class" referring to the (Column#, Text, Row#) portion.

```
$worksheet.usedrange.autofilter(1, "NO DATA", 2)
$worksheet.usedrange.offset(1,0).specialcells(12).Entirerow.Delete() 
$worksheet.ShowAllData()
```

This code works but gives me the wrong data set (I'm left with everything I wanted deleted, and it still filters from row 1 and not row 2.

any help would be great.

Comment: this may not be do-able for you ... but have you thot about exporting to a CSV and working with that? PoSh can handle CSV files directly, simply, and _quickly_. [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks, I have looked into it, but my CSV knowledge is even worse than my Excel/ powershell knowledge and Ive got 320 lines of code working with powershell to Excel that I cant go back on.
I was able to find a usable solution to this question though

Comment: go with what works! [*grin*] however, if your data is 2d, then CSV format files are FAR easier to work with - and almost always faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for this:

```
$StartRow = 3
$RowCnt = $worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
$worksheet.Range("A$($StartRow):A$($RowCnt)").AutoFilter(1,"<>NO DATA")
$worksheet.usedrange.offset($StartRow,0).specialcells(12).Entirerow.Delete() 
$worksheet.ShowAllData()
```

Comment: I was able to find a solution, but yes. This is essentially what the solution is :)

Answer (score 1):

was able to find a solution, it was actually just as simple as I expected :/

```
$SubCon_Vs_NOA.range("A2").autofilter(1,"<>NO DATA")
$SubCon_Vs_NOA.range("A3:A$rows").Entirerow.Delete() 
$SubCon_Vs_NOA.ShowAllData()
```